# Why am I unable to access a BOOL directly: _myBool?

Tags: objective-c

I have a private BOOL in a class

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myBool;
```

I want to override the getter and setter so I can either synchronize it, or dispatch it to a serial queue.

```
- (BOOL)myBool
{
    __block BOOL test = NO;
    dispatch_sync(self.shouldShowBannerQueue, ^{
        test = _myBool; //This does not work. I get an error "Use of undeclared _myBool"
    });

    return test;
}
```

I cannot override the setter for the same reason. I cannot directly access _myBool.

Comment: Why is this tagged `[swift]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the accessor methods, the implicit synthesis will not happen and you won't have the `_myBool` variable. But you can simply add an instance variable to the class and use it to back the accessor methods.

Comment: Or add `@synthesize myBool;`

Comment: @BorisVerebsky Or `@synthesize myBool = _myBool;` to be equivalent to the implicit behaviour. Personally I prefer to add the ivar if I'm writing custom accessors, since I feel the `@synthesize` hints that they would have default behaviour.